# Remove all <word> tags

Tags: python, regex

I have to write a program to remove all expressions of the form `<word>` and `</word>` where word is any sequence of letters (lower and upper case) and
Remove all expressions of the form `<word ..... >` and `</word>` where word is the same as before. For example, remove `<a href=”wwang3.htm” class=”c l”>`

Until now my code looks like this:

```
def remove_1( file_location ):
    """"""

    import re
    file_variable = open( file_location )
    lines = file_variable.read()

    p = re.findall('<.*?>', lines)
    print p

    substitution = re.compile('<.*?>')
    print substitution.subn( ' ', p )
```

I get an error that points to the `print.substitution.subn( ' ', p)` in which it says that I expected a string or buffer while running the program.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to substitute into the string "p". However, p is the result of findall which is a list.

I would suggest doing it like this:

```
lines = file_variable.read()
print re.subn('<.*?>', ' ', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

`lines` contains the string you should pass to `subn`

```
print substitution.subn( ' ', lines )
```